# Excel VBA Selection.replace do not replace everything

Tags: vba, excel

Basically what I am trying to do is to imitate the replace button with VBA code. I use the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Blad1.Activate
    Blad1.Cells.Select
    Selection.Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

This replaces all of the dots, but in some cases it replaces the dots with whitespaces instead of commas. Why is this?

Comment: It works just fine for me. Can you give an example where it is not working?

Comment: Well, I have a lot of data, and it works fine in the first columns but when I come to column V and W it skips a lot of the cells.

Comment: would it be possible for me to see Col V/W data in a sample file?

Comment: Sure. Is it possible for me to send it too you through stackoverflow in anyway or do I need your email?

Comment: upload the file in www.wikisend.com and share the link here.

Comment: Ok, thanks, here is the link: http://wikisend.com/download/479318/sample_file.xlsx

Comment: Just tested it on this file and it works just fine...

Comment: If your original file with the code doesn't have any confidential data then I can check that as well?

Comment: Hmm, well column D,V and W are the only important ones, so maybe I should try to only change those then.

Comment: Ok.. I just have an idea (a shot in the dark)... What are the regional settings for your pc?

Comment: Swedish. That is why I am trying to change dots to commas, I want excel to recognize the cells as numbers.

Comment: Then I think I know what is going on :) Let me do some tests and get back to you...

Comment: Swedish(Finland) or Swedish(Sweden)?

Comment: Swedish(Sweden). Also, just trying to change V and W didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oRange As Range, aCell As Range, bCell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ExitLoop As Boolean
    Dim SearchString As String, FoundAt As String
    On Error GoTo Err
    Set ws = Blad1
    Set oRange = ws.Cells

    oRange.NumberFormat = "@"

    SearchString = "."
    Set aCell = oRange.Find(What:=SearchString, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell
        Do While InStr(1, aCell.Formula, ".") > 0
            aCell.Formula = Replace(aCell.Formula, ".", ",")
        Loop
        Do While ExitLoop = False
            Set aCell = oRange.FindNext(After:=aCell)

            If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                Do While InStr(1, aCell.Formula, ".") > 0
                    aCell.Formula = Replace(aCell.Formula, ".", ",")
                Loop
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop
    End If
    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that did work. I am guessing the thousands separator was responsible somehow, after really looking through the result I saw that only the cells with more than 4 numbers were troublesome.